# Execute an application from Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm doing some tests working with processes from java. In particular I am starting the compiler of C# to which I pass the path of a source file to compile it. The code is the following:

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add("C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\csc.exe");
values.add("d:\\source\\program.cs");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(values);
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader brProcess = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String output;
while ((output = brProcess.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(output);
```

At the end I print the output of the compiler and I see that it is correct but the executable is not generated. If I execute the same instruction from the command line it works perfectly.

I appreciate the help to find out why the application does not work.

Comment: You'd like to pass the program.cs as a parameter for your app execution?

Comment: "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\csc.exe -out:My.exe d:\\source\\program.cs" try this.

Comment: In the example code, the source to compile is a constant but it doesn't matter if I send it as a parameter.

Comment: Maciej, it still doesn't work with the -out parameter

Comment: What directory do you expect the executable to appear in?

Comment: I expect to see the executable in the same folder as the source code

Comment: Is that where csc.exe will put it?  Or will it out it in the current directory?

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that I wasn't specifying the output path.